# Consistent Byte Representation of invalid chars

Tags: .net, arrays, string, encoding, byte

Apologies if this has been answered somewhere, but if it has, I couldn't find it.

I am doing some manipulations with byte arrays, and have noticed that when converting invalid chars (for example, the byte 0x9C) , it gets interpreted as a "?". Therefore, when I convert it back into a byte, it comes out as 0x3F.

My issue is that parts of the byte arrays are ASCII, but others are checksums that may contain invalid chars like this one. I would like to be able to convert the entire array into a string for convenience. Is there an encoding that will yield ASCII for normal characters and ensure that converting an invalid char to a string and back will yield the same byte?

Answer (score 0):

May not work for others, but I found that by using

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(...)
```

and

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(...)
```

as opposed to other encodings prevented the values in byte arrays from being changed to "?" and ASCII characters were still interpreted correctly.

Comment: There are still values that can cause you to get invalid data. If you need to represent a byte[] as a string you should be using `Convert.ToBase64String(` and `Convert.FromBase64String(` Also, if you plan on sending data between computers `System.Text.Encoding.Default` can be different from system to system. Just take your checksums and make them their own byte[] and append the base64 text of them on to the end of the string.

Comment: Default varies across machines, users and time. It's seldom the right choice but might have a chance of working the context of the back-and-forth transformation described in the question.

Comment: I should add, I found the default on my machine to be System.Text.Encoding.SBCSCodePageEncoding, and have changed the code to specify that. It very well may still give invalid data, but so far it is working properly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "normal characters" but you are asking for an encoding that can decode arbitrary sequences of arbitrary byte values 0-255. It would need to be for a character set with 256 codepoints, have 1-byte code units, encode all codepoints in one code unit, be in the .NET Base Class Libraries and the character set be a subset of Unicode.

ISO 8859-1 and CP437 are two that meet these requirements. You can check whether they map your "normal characters" to "normal characters" in Unicode. (Hint: ISO 8859-1 has the all same characters as the [C0 Control and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) and the C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement blocks.)

BTW—are you sure that regions of your data format are text encoded in ASCII and not some other character encoding?